# Monitor a folder and ETL xml data to oracle

Tags: oracle, etl, data-integration

Is there any tool I can use to:
monitor a folder, when a xml file is added, it checks its name validate it(if exists in a list of names), validates it against a schema xsd, and extract data contained in xml and load it to an oracle database, if any error occurs in that process it rejects the file (write its name in a file of rejected files). I don't expect it to be able to fullfill all these features but at least help me with the monitoring and automating the process.
thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any ETL or data integration tool should be able to do that. I’ve implemented a project that had most of those features in the past using Pentaho Data Integration.